# Android AppWidgetProviderInfo icon id

Tags: android, resources, widget

Android's `AppWidgetProviderInfo` class contains an integer `icon` field. I want to get hold of the icon as a `Drawable`.

I presume the icon id needs to be resolved against some package's `Resources`. The widget provider is not part of my app, so my own app resources as returned by `getResources()` are no use. Neither are the system resources given by `Resources.getSystem()`.

How can I convert this integer id into a Drawable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PackageManager` and [`getResourcesForApplication()`](http://goo.gl/kIz0x).

Comment: Can you please provide some code on how to do this, I am using this currently but still getting a NameNotFoundException:


        Resources resources = packageManager.getResourcesForActivity(installedWidget.provider);
        widget.setImage(resources.getDrawable(installedWidget.icon));

Answer (score 1):

Like CommonsWare has said you will need to use [getResourcesForApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication(java.lang.String))
here is how you can use it and also since lollipop there is a [loadIcon()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#loadIcon(android.content.Context,%20int)) function that's a lot easier to use

```
Drawable icon = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    icon = info.loadIcon(this, density);
} else {
    try {
        String packageName = info.provider.getPackageName();
        Resources resources = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
        icon = resources.getDrawable(info.icon);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```